# How to set $PATH for npm?

Tags: node.js

I have the issue with `npm`.

```
$ npm search
npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "search"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! search must be called with arguments
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/pavel/GitHub/react-samples/1_intro/2_JSX_babel/npm-debug.log
```

I'm not shure, but I think issue with `$PATH` variable.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/pavel/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin
```

My node does not registered in `$PATH`.

Please, help me fix this issue. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear "**search must be called with arguments**", that is not about $Path !! You must define what are looking for, in other words **search-term**.

> npm search [-l|--long] [--json] [--parseable] [--no-description] [search terms ...]

for example:

> npm search redis

and you'll get a list of modules (name, description, author, date ...)

For more details use the following command line :

> npm help search

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"

It might solve your issue.

Comment: unfortunately again `npm search` get `npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "search"`

Comment: Did you use any arguments for search? Check the response from @Wajdi below.